# With CRISPR-mediated gene editing, can the PAM for the guide RNA also be site of the desired edit?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, crispr

I'm hoping to use CRISPR-Cas9 in yeast to change a single nucleotide in a gene of interest. While there are a couple potential guide RNA sequences I could use, the best option's PAM sequence (TGG) it contains the site of my desired edit (TGG > TTG). Would there be any issue with this?